# Oracle Synonym equivalent to refer to active table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, synonym

I have a job in oracle which populates the table for frontend system.
To populate this table we map many other other tables.
The frontend refers this for any search they do.
In order to make the data always available to frontend we have two copies of the table.
A synonym refers to the active table.
The other table gets populated as part of the job and once it completes the synonym is swapped.
In case we have new changes like adding new column the inactive table gets populated and then synonym is swapped.
Every day we truncate and load the inactive table. Once done swap the synonym.
The frontend query always refer to synonym.

How to do this in postgres.
One way i could think is put the active table name in another table and read this entry and use it for application.
This means every where i have to make the query as dynamic or put IF/ELSE and write the same query twice with diff table names.
Is there a better we have of doing this is postgres.
I have 13.3 version

customer_table_1
(customer_id numeric,
customer_name text,
.
.
)

customer_table_2
(customer_id numeric,
customer_name text,
.
.
)

Comment: Why not just use a view?

Comment: Or simply rename the tables (in a single transaction)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think rename of the table will work. By view you mean put union of two tables in it. This will not work as after the job completes we will have record in both tables. I cannot truncate/delete the data in inactive table after the job completes because in case issues are noted due to the job afterwards, as backup we need to point to the other table.

Comment: No, a view instead of a synonym. First it points to table 1 then it points to table 2

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name i think this should work